# Does James Cameron work with/for NASA?

Tags: directors

I've heard that he helped with some space-videos with NASA.

Comment: *Cameron is a member of the NASA Advisory Council and is working on the project to put cameras on an upcoming manned Mars mission. Cameron has also given speeches and raised money for the Mars Society, a non-profit organization lobbying for the colonization of Mars.* - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Cameron#Personal_life)

Comment: Cool! It will be very interesting to see these things from an artistic point of view, I think Cameron (James) has always been ahead of his time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a director's career outside of filmmaking with no regards to movies/tv

Comment: If NASA and Cameron get together, they could make cool movies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes he does work with **NASA**, Since 2005, see this [article](http://www.space.com/783-director-james-cameron-works-nasa-future-mars-mission.html) for more infos:

> Two years ago, not long after the Columbia accident claimed the lives
>   of seven astronauts, Cameron attended his first meeting as a member of
>   the NASA Advisory Council, a body that counsels the agency's
>   administrator.
>
> Slowly, he became more engaged. Now, he's working as an investigator
>   on a camera for a Mars mission set for this decade.

Comment: You might want to consider quoting the essential parts of the article to flesh this answer out a little more and differentiate it from a mere link-only answer.